# C: How to sort a Struct by one of its element? Can't use pointers

Tags: c, function, sorting, struct

How do I sort struct like this one:

```
typedef struct
{
    int weight;
    int price;
    Color color;
    Equip equip;
}Cars;
```

by one of it's attributes like price, or weight? Automobil array is previously declared.
I can't use pointers, and any other built-in function.

```
Cars automobil[5]; 
Cars mobilOne={};

for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    if((i+1)==5)
    {
        break;
    }else
    {
        if (automobil[i].weight> automobil[i+1].weight)
        {
            mobilOne = automobil[i];
            automobil[i] = automobil[i+1];
            automobil[i+1] = mobilOne;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to do this, this way, but it does not do anything...
Also if someone could tell me, how can I pass a struct like this one into a function I would be really thankful!

Comment: You would have a compile error because you spelled "wieght" wrong.

Comment: You're on your way to "invent" [*bubble sort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). Unfortunately you need *two* loops, nested inside each other, for it to work.

Comment: Is your objective to get a sort job done, or to create your own sort routine?  i.e. are you able to use `qsort()`?  It already exists, and is very versatile.  And why in the world can you not use pointers?  Is this an exercise for a class you are taking?

Comment: probably I could use some kind of a function, by the teacher did't mention this. I think, that I could use only things that I am aware of.

Comment: "I think, that I could use only things that I am aware of." --> then why post on SO?

Comment: `qsort(.)` is included in in the C standard library.  Would your instructor exclude its use?

Comment: I guess I could use it

Comment: Rather than looping whilst i<5, why not make it i<4 then you don't need the if statement

Comment: You need to know what exactly you are allowed to use and what not. You teacher needs to tell you this. Using the standard function `qsort` or rewriting your own sorting function are two different things. Both approaches are OK depending on what your teacher wants you to learn.

Comment: As `qsort(.)` requires the use of pointers (in its comparison function), by the rules you are working to, it is not yet allowed.  (unfortunately)

Comment: Has your class covered any standard sorting algorithm ([bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), [quick sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)) on scalar types (`int`, `float`, etc.) before now?  If so, the basic principle is the same, except that you're doing your comparisons against a single member of the type.  If not, slap your instructor for me for making this assignment much harder than it needs to be.

Comment: @JohnBode unfortunately not, but I've previously learned a little bit about sorting algorithms, and etc, but structs are something new to me (pretty similiar to classes, but not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into implementation details here is a procedural algorithm for a bubble sort (not in C): *[Bubble Sort Algorithm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/bubble_sort_algorithm.htm)*.  Note, as mentioned in comments, this bubble sort implementation uses nested loops.

One other item to keep in mind:  In order to switch two objects, a third temporary object of the same type needs to be used. For example:

```
int temp
int arr1[]={2,5,7,2,9,1,8,0,5,2,1};
int count = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0])
for(int i = 0; i < count-1; i++ )
{
    if(arr1[i]>arr1[i+1])
    {
        temp = arr1[i];
        arr1[i] = arr1[i+1];
        arr[i+1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Because you are sorting on a single member of a collection of members, the assignment swapping routine will need to swap *every* member each time the condition for a swap exists, i.e. although determining if the swap condition exists only considers one member, swapping will include *all* members: `weight`, `price`, `Color` and `Equip`.  And, if `Color` and `Equip` are of `struct` type (your post does not specify), then each member of these objects belonging to array elements being compared, will also need to be swapped.

*You should look forward to eventually using pointers as this will significantly reduce the number of assignment statements needed to complete this sort.*

Answer (score 2):

OK, well first what you are trying to do is not quite as bad as some people might tell you as for small N bubble sort is still pretty fast. The following will do you and of course you need a double loop:

```
int main() {
    Cars automobil[NC];
    // Initialiase automobil here

    for (int i = 0; i < NC - 1; ++i) {
        int am = i;
        for (int j = i+1; j < NC; ++j) {
            if ( automobil[am].weight > automobil[j].weight )
                am = j;
        }

        if ( am != i) {
            Cars tmp = automobil[am];
            automobil[am] = automobil[i];
            automobil[i] = tmp;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NC; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", automobil[i].weight);

}
```

Notice that we can copy structs but even here we try to do it as little as possible.

However, it's very easy to say "I'll never have more than ten cars" and then find you are trying to sort several thousand so I would urge you to learn and understand qsort():

```
int carsSort(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return ((Cars *) a)->weight - ((Cars *) b)->weight;
}

int main() {
    Cars automobil[NC];
    // Initialiase automobil here

    qsort(automobil, NC, sizeof *automobil, carsSort);

    for (int i = 0; i < NC; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", automobil[i].weight);
}
```

John

PS: in reply to "how do I pass the array to a function?" remember one of the many wise sayings of K&R: "When an array name is passed to a function, what is passed is the location of the beginning of the array".

Hence:

```
int carsSort(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return ((Cars *) a)->weight - ((Cars *) b)->weight;
}

void sortThem(Cars autom[]) {
    qsort(autom, NC, sizeof *autom, carsSort);
}

int main() {
    Cars automobil[NC];       
    // Initialiase automobil here

    sortThem(automobil);

    for (int i = 0; i < NC; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", automobil[i].weight);
}
```

Inside sortThem() "autom" is a variable whose value is the address of automobil[0].